# Magnetic field around unplugged TV

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have no physics background, so bear with me.  I found one of those magnetic field apps for iPhone.  I wanted it to see if it could help me find wires inside my walls to avoid when drilling, etc (although I ordered a stud finder/multiscanner for this purpose).  At any rate, no matter which of these apps I use, the iPhone gives me high readings (up to 1600 microteslas) near the power button on my unplugged LcD TV.  What gives?  Is my TV radioactive?

Thanks, Sarah

Comment: The speakers in LCD TV are usually towards the bottom of the TV. The speakers have magnets in them. That's what is giving you that reading.

Comment: Thanks Mechanic!  That explains it!

Comment: In addition electricity and magnetism are not radioactive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay

Comment: Thanks anna v.  Believe it or not, I took physics years ago but I thought maybe radioactivity caused a magnetic field?, not that magnets were radioactive.  If that makes any sense.  I'm confused.  Look, I'm 54 and I took physics at 20 or 21.  It's been a while.